# tablesorter grouping widget customization

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I have a requirement where I need the ability to group by a particular column in a table based on the users choice. I need to mirror the dynamic grouping functionality as shown in jqgrid documenation. I am using the table sorter grouping mechanism.Initially I tried jqGrid which worked well but we were not able to customize the css according to our requirement. I am using tablesorter along with the grouping widget.
Now using this combo I can see that you can group by all the columns in the table by just clicking on the column header, which i need to limit. So, basically I need to load the table with a particular column grouped and then when the user clicks on the other columns only sorting should happen. Also,on grouping the widget is considering only the first letter instead of the whole word. I checked out the grouping code and there is a split function being used which should be modified. Can anyone please point me in the right direction for achieving my target

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grouping widget allows you to set it to group by letter, word, separator, date and to disable grouping of a column - see the "Header Class Names" section for a [full list class names](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-grouping.html) that can be used.

In your case, use `group-word` class name on the column you want to group by words, and `group-false` to disable grouping ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/1830/))

HTML

```
<table class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="group-word">AlphaNumeric</th>
            <th class="group-false">Numeric</th>
            <th class="group-false">Animals</th>
            <th class="group-false">Sites</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Script

```
$('table').tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',
    sortList: [ [0, 0] ],
    widgets: ['zebra', 'group']
});
```

CSS (collapsable arrow)

```
/* collapsed arrow */
 tr.group-header td i {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 4px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #888;
    border-right: 4px solid #888;
    border-left: 4px solid transparent;
    margin-right: 7px;
    user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
}
tr.group-header.collapsed td i {
    border-top: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
    border-left: 5px solid #888;
    border-right: 0;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: First of all thanks for your prompt response. Initially I passed the parameter sortList: [ [1, 1] ] to group based on the 2nd column which is working perfectly. Then i added the group headers as suggested and its working well. The only problem I am facing is that when I click on the other column headers the initial grouping is removed. I know that if you press SHIFT and then click on the column header it will sort within the grouping. Can I write / modify any jquery so that this behaviour can be achieved without the need of pressing the SHIFT key.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you want, but try the [`sortForce` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#sortforce) to always sort that desired column first ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/1831/))

Comment: Yes that's what I exactly wanted... the sortforce option did the trick. Thanks a lot... !!!! The only thing that I have to do now is to change the expand and contract buttons.

Comment: It's all done with css! There is an `<i></i>` element in the group header which is styled: `<tr class="group-header"><td colspan="4"><i></i><span class="group-name">abc</span><span class="group-count"> (#)</span></td></tr>`. A `collapsed` class name is added to the `group-header` when a group is collapsed. I added the specific css to my answer.

Comment: Yes I got that ... one problem I am having is that I want to increase the colspan for my grouping rows by 1 . So, is there any way by which I can achieve this.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean; colspans within the tbody are not currently supported. Can you provide more details or a mockup of what you want?